# Stop currently running Ida Script mid execution

Tags: ida

I ran an ida script and forgot to account for an infinite loop that keeps making a dialog pop up. Is there any keyboard command that will stop an Ida script from running mid execution? Thank you. I'm using Ida Freeware 7.0

Answer (score 1):

This is probably unhelpful, but one way to handle that is to build something into your IDA script that will gracefully handle termination. The difficulty is not in whether IDA will allow you to kill the popup but in regaining focus on the IDA window. When I tried it just now on a generic infinite loop, IDA pops up a dialog that says "Running script" and you can click "Cancel" to end it.

In the infinite loop, make sure that you use a dialog that allows you to kill the script - use either a custom dialog or use something like idc.AskYN(), and then build in a hook that kills the script on use of a particular input.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ida_kernwin module which has a function „user_cancelled()“ returning a bool. Call it within a loop in order to determine whether the script was asked to terminate, for example via ctrl-break.